# How to send propert from jsp file to a action method in liferay?

Tags: jsp, liferay

My jsp file contains the following code:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="patientProfileURL" name="editPatientProfile">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/patientProfile.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL> 
<p><a href="<%= patientProfileURL%>">Edit Profile</a></p>
```

I want to send a parameter to editPatientProfile() when the user clicks on "Edit Profile". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question because you're already passing a parameter. in the URL you're building. So similarly, you'll want to add `<portlet:param name="" value="" />`.

Thats it!

See the sample below:

```xml
<portlet:actionURL var="patientProfileURL" name="editPatientProfile">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/patientProfile.jsp" />
    <portlet:param name="myParam" value="myValue" />
</portlet:actionURL> 
<p><a href="<%= patientProfileURL%>">Edit Profile</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks RP. I had some problem with this tag. I think it is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String url="/patientProfile.jsp?urParameter"+urParameterValue;

<portlet:actionURL var="patientProfileURL" name="editPatientProfile">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/patientProfile.jsp" />
<portlet:param name="myParam" value="<%=url%>" />

<p><a href="<%= patientProfileURL%>">Edit Profile</a></p>
```